# Windows Service GUI Editor

Tags: windows, open-source, windows-services

I am looking for a GUI that lets me manage and edit Windows Services.  The Windows control panel "**Services**" explorer doesn't let me do any editing of a service's set-up.

I found these two StackExchange questions that go part of the way to editing service parameters and information:

- [how to change path to executable to a service](https://superuser.com/questions/222238/how-to-change-path-to-executable-to-a-service), and
- [scheduling starting a service after another service](https://superuser.com/questions/188532/scheduling-starting-a-service-after-another-service)

These two examples use the SC.exe (Service Control) command line tool.

After all the time we've had Windows in its current state, I was hoping we had a GUI tool out there that does the same thing for tweaks and '*repairs*' to services.  I'm posting here to learn if someone knows of such a utility?

For bonus points :-) I'd also like to know if you can use system environment variables in a service's file path?  E.g. something like:

- "%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe" "-classpath" . . .

I appreciate that such a path wouldn't take effect without a reboot or restart of the service.  However, that kind of set-up, it would make life somewhat more straightforward.  I'm not holding my breath, just asking.  I am more optimistic to see a real editor after almost years of the 'Services' explorer window.  I'm sure there's an open source or other tool out there ...

Thanks in advance, will.

Comment: Check out [Windows Service Manager](http://tools.sysprogs.org/srvman/) and [Advanced Windows Service Manager](http://securityxploded.com/winservicemanager.php).

Answer (score 2):

Following [Karan](https://superuser.com/users/138343/karan)'s comment I can confirm that:

- [Windows Service Manager](http://tools.sysprogs.org/srvman/) ... ***Works*** as requested.  This includes the use of %JAVA_HOME% in the start-up command.
- [Advanced Windows Service Manager](http://securityxploded.com/winservicemanager.php) ... Does **not** do what I'm looking for, edit the service properties.

  - It does some things but not as much more than the Windows Services explorer.
  - Most of all it is a virus check for services, which is handy when you need it.

I'm very happy using %JAVA_HOME% works; that will save heaps of maintenance when I install the Java updates.  I am not sure how one can escape the "%"-s on the **sc**.exe command line.

Thanks to [Karan](https://superuser.com/users/138343/karan) for the pointing me in the right direction.

... w